# How to prevent compilation succeeding via diagnostic?

Tags: vb.net, roslyn

I'm using Roslyn as supplied in the VS14 ctp 4 release, but I can't seem to make the compilation not succeed when my diagnostic reveals an issue that should be treated as an error. The two ways I've tried are below.

```
 Sub AddError(msg As String, d As Action(Of Diagnostic), st As SyntaxTree, offset As Integer, s As IndexSpan)
   Dim r As New DiagnosticDescriptor(DiagnosticId, "", MessageFormat, Category, DiagnosticSeverity.Error, True)
   Dim q = Diagnostic.Create(DiagnosticId, Category, String.Format(MessageFormat, msg), DiagnosticSeverity.Error, True, 0, False, Description,, Location.Create(st, TextSpan.FromBounds(offset + s.Index + 1, offset + s.Index + s.Span)))
   d(q)
'   d(Diagnostic.Create(r, Location.Create(st, TextSpan.FromBounds(offset + s.Index + 1, offset + s.Index + s.Span)), msg))
 End Sub
```

I don't know if it is an issue with the IDE not propagating the error? or I need to now do something different to prevent compilation?

Comment: Do you mean you don't see the error at all?

Comment: @svick The error gets shown in the error window.
But according to Intellisense on the error enum 

**Something not allowed by the language or other authority**
Should prevent successful compilation

Comment: I've also tried ticking the setting Treat Warnings as Errors, and compilation succeeded and the code then runs.